# Why getuserMedia audio is not working in Safari 11.1 of Mac OS

Tags: javascript, safari, webrtc, getusermedia

I am trying to play the getUserMedia audio example referenced by webrtc [DEMO](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/audio/).

It's working on all browsers but not on **Safari 11.1** of Mac OS. Interestingly  it's working on Safari of iPad.

```js
var tempStream;
// Put variables in global scope to make them available to the browser console.
const audio = document.querySelector('audio');

const constraints = window.constraints = {
  audio: true,
  video: true
};

function handleSuccess(stream) {
  const audioTracks = stream.getAudioTracks();
  tempStream = stream; // make variable available to browser console
}

function audioPlay() {
  audio.srcObject = tempStream;
  audio.play();
}

document.querySelector('#audioPlay').addEventListener('click', audioPlay);

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(handleSuccess);
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <audio id="gum-local" controls></audio> <br />
  <button id="audioPlay"> <b> PLAY AUDIO </b> </button>
</div>
```

Comment: try `preload` in `audio` tag

Comment: It's not working